# How to get a jar with source attachment for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

We just upgraded our old Hibernate (3.*) to the newest release and after half an hour of searching I was not able to find a .jar file with source attachment of Hibernate 4.1.7. Do you have any ideas where can it be found? I tried sourceforge, Hibernate's official page and I checked out Github too. It will be also fine if you point me out some tutorials about building a jar file with source attachment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.7.Final/) at the JBoss repository (which is sync'ed to central regularly)?

As for building a source JAR, it really is dependent on your build methodology, but eg. using Maven it is supremely easy:

```
mvn source:jar
```

Cheers,